# Linux filezilla Error: Pageant failed to answer challenge

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, sftp, filezilla

So for a long time I have had no issues with keys and filezilla.

This morning I woke up, attempted to sftp into my Raspberry Pi and I get this:

**Problem**

```
Status: Connecting to pi:2222...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
Command:    keyfile "/home/cx/.ssh/id_rsa_putty"
Command:    open "cybex@pi" 2222
Error:  Pageant failed to answer challenge
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I am using the putty key from my Windows Putty.

**Tried:**
I have recreated new keys - openssh (for the sake of it), downloaded and installed puttygen for linux and regenerated keys (as this is what I used before), rebooted my Pi

None of this works, I cannot find anyone who has had the same issue,

Anyone know why this happens, I am at a complete loss!

Answer (score 1):

have the same problem with FileZilla 3.39.0

via [mon all logs](https://dwaves.de/2017/06/15/linux-monitor-all-logs-in-real-time-d-follow-all-show-changes-to-log-files-under-varlog/) script, the user-admin can debug the problem:

this happens when:

it is

Permissions 0644 for '/home/user/.ssh/crother_id_rsa' are too open

## the solution

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/crother_id_rsa

```
==> /var/log/auth.log <==
Mar 20 16:01:54 hostname gnome-keyring-daemon[906]: the /usr/bin/ssh-add command failed: Child process exited with code 1
Mar 20 16:01:54 hostname gnome-keyring-daemon[906]: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#012@

WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @#012@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@#012

Permissions 0644 for '/home/user/.ssh/crother_id_rsa' are too open.

#012It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.#012This private key will be ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is awkward...

**A simple system restart solved my issue,**

for the record,

**Filezilla: which keys to use**

> linux puttygen keys work (RSA Key tested)
>
> OpenSSH linux keys work (that is the built in ssh uitility RSA and ECDSA keys tested)

Hope this helps!